# Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise with ReSharper 10 Ultimate -- Cannot be properly resolved

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, resharper, atscript

I have **Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise, version 14.0.24720.00 Update 1** as well as **ReSharper 10 Ultimate, version 10.0.2** installed.  I have a typescript file that is using AtScript syntax to refer to the Angular2 directive module, as its annotation.  However, ReSharper is stating the following error:

> Symbol 'Directive' cannot be properly resolved, probably it is located in inaccessible module.

Below is the full error tooltip.

[image]

The application compiles and runs as expected, and the angular portions of the application also function as desired.  It appears as though this is a ReSharper false negative.  Is anyone familiar with a workaround other that simply disabling ReSharper or ignoring the warning?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The issue is simply a bug with the latest version of ReSharper, if you Suspend ReSharper the issue simply goes away and all the source code works as expected.

**Update**

This has since been addressed in the **[ReSharper 2016.1](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2016/04/14/resharper-ultimate-2016-1-is-released/)** version.

Comment: For what it's worth, this error - not necessarily in this precise scenario - is showing up for me in 2016.2.2, with TS 2.0.3, with the --strictNullChecks flag on.

Comment: I am also seeing the error still in 2016.2.2 with TS 2.0.3.  Typescript compiles fine - but it is complaining about momentjs.

Comment: I'm seeing it in R# 2016.2.2 and 2016.3 EAP8, using TS 2.0.6. Like everyone else, TS is compiling fine, but Resharper complains. I think it started for me about the time I turned on `strictNullChecks`. Filed this bug: https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/803955?flash_digest=b7c62e7ca4e90ba381450c63d6573661eb70ef7b

Answer (score 2):

As of 02/2016, the issue is ***fixed*** in the ReSharper Ultimate 10.1 EAP 3

this version still has some other typescript issues though

**Original answer, explaining why it couldn't work in previous versions:**

Had the same setup and same issue. I strongly believe this is related to: "moduleResolution": "node"

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/oauth?state=%2Fissue%2FRSRP-273158

> Unfortunately, no way now. We're working on node.js support for the next ReSharper version.

Comment: Yet there is probably no other help than a new Resharper release

Comment: Thank you, your answer led me to the solution. You can download the R# EAP version here: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+10.1+EAP

Comment: I can confirm this fixed the issue... I used 10.1 EAP 7.

Comment: I used 10.1 31 Mar EAP8 and it did not fix this issue.

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround, if you are using angular2 from your node_modules folder, then you can reference it directly instead of relying on the new node module resolution. For example you can do:

```
import {Directive} from '../../node_modules/angular2/core';
```

Comment: Indeed it is a work around, however; I'm looking for a permanent fix...  What risks does this carry with it?

Comment: If you move the file, you'll need to update the relative path of all your imports...

Answer (score 1):

If updating to latest ReSharper version does not work and this only affects `.js(x)` and `.ts(x)` files you only need to suspend those. You can do that by going to ReSharper -> Options -> Unclick JavaScript and TypeScript.

[image]

Comment: Although it's not my preferred solution I have no choice but have to do same. Nothing else helped and I tried many ideas found on the internet. However instead of disabling Resharper for ts files at all, I prefer to disable code inspecition for ts files so I still can use Code Cleanup function. Or even better, I just removed that one concrete error from popping up in the Inspectiuon Severity menu. I see this error reported for years, but hopefully, it will get fixed by JetBrains in some future patch.

Answer (score 0):

It could be Resharper problem. disable it from tools->option->Resharper Ultimate->General->Suspend Now and the errors will be hide.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same problem on one of my modules on Resharper 2017.1 in Visual Studio 2017.

[image]

But after updating my Resharper to 2017.2.2, that solved the problem.

[image]