# Symbol 'XXX' cannot be properly resolved error in Angular2, warned by Resharper

Tags: angular, typescript, resharper, rxjs

After I forced closed VS2015 and reopened it, Resharper shows this error in many places:

[image: Symbol 'test' cannot be properly resolved, probably it is located in inaccessible module]

The error message is:

> Symbol 'test' cannot be properly resolved, probably it is located in
>   inaccessible module

It only happens in rxjs with words like `filter`, `flatMap` and `map`. I have tried updating Resharper to 2017.1 and cleaning the Reshparper cache folder, but it did not fix the error.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

// Observable class extensions
import 'rxjs/add/observable/from';
// Observable operators
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

var list = new Array<any>();
Observable.from(list).map(i=>i.test) //i is recognised as interface Object here
     .subscribe(item => {
     item.length.other = '';
);
```

I also created a bug report here:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-464459#u=1492657450427

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise with ReSharper 10 Ultimate -- Cannot be properly resolved](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34592390/visual-studio-2015-enterprise-with-resharper-10-ultimate-cannot-be-properly-r)