# ReSharper: Symbol cannot be properly resolved

Tags: visual-studio-2017, resharper

In the last week, I've started having an issue with ReSharper giving me a "Symbol cannot be properly resolved" error with `@angular/core` components. However, I know that those components are properly installed and my solutions still builds, publishes, and runs correctly.

This has been addressed in the past ([Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise with ReSharper 10 Ultimate — Cannot be properly resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34592390/visual-studio-2015-enterprise-with-resharper-10-ultimate-cannot-be-properly-r)) and it seems that the only answer was to disable ReSharper and wait for them to put out an update resolving the issue. Following [the instructions mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2675872/7848128), I was able to set up hotkeys for disabling/enabling Resharper.

The issue goes away when ReSharper is disabled. However, I was wondering if a better answer has come out in the last two years... disabling ReSharper doesn't exactly seem like a good solution.

(I'm using Visual Studio Community 2017 15.8.1 and ReSharper 2018.1.4)

[image]

Comment: this keeps happening as of today with vs2022 and the latest resharper, going to disable r# for tsc once again

Answer (score 52, accepted):

EDIT '19

Everytime R# gets an update, this answer gets upvoted, so I assume this problem occurs when something goes wrong after updating R# to the newest version. The solution still applies for me.

I usually do the same workaround, without reinstalling it and after I have updated to the latest version of R#:

1. Clear caches in: ReSharper > Options > Environment > General
2. Suspend Now in: Tools > Options > ReSharper
3. Exit Visual Studio
4. Delete .vs and obj folders
5. Open Visual Studio
6. Resume Now in: Tools > Options > ReSharper

Works for me all the time, but again, I am working under C# and the "solution" might not apply to you.

Comment: It almost worked... now the `@angular/core` components are showing correctly but now a bunch of native components (Like `Number` and `Object` aren't working... maybe if I try it again.

Comment: I expanded upon your instructions to get it to work... between steps 3 and 4, I deleted the ReSharper settings files (ReSharper > Manage Options > Reset All Settings), and then uninstalled and reinstalled ReSharper. If you add an edit to your answer, I'll happily accept it.

Comment: It looks like what have fixed it was actually reinstalling it maybe? Have you tried before?

Comment: The original steps worked for me without a reinstall.

Comment: Visual Studio 16.2 update just triggered it for me. This solution as written continues to work.

Comment: Ok, so this didn't work for me, and nothing else that I've tried has. However, after hours of trial and error, copying the the file where the missing symbol was located to a new name, then deleting the original file, letting ReSharper finish reanalyzing, and finally renaming the copied file back to the original name actually fixed it!

Comment: I got the issue after updating VS2019, the solution worked for me as well!

Comment: Update to latest VS 2019 triggered this for me as well and was also able to fix it with your step by step guide. Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me after updating visual studio.  intellisense for typescript is working again.

Comment: Does anyone know how to fix this when it is happening in TeamCity's ReSharper code inspections?

Comment: I fixed TeamCity by reinstalling the build agent, deleting the cache when uninstalling.

Comment: I won't do this every time for every project so I didn't bother and just permanently suspended R# so +1 for figuring out what JetBrains seems to still not have the willingness or ability to fix.

Answer (score 1):

Usually it happens when you upgrade Resharper/Visual Studio to the newest version.
Sometimes accepted answer doesn't help.

As a temporary solution before official fix you can set all `*.ts` files to be ignored by Resharper.

`Resharper -> Options -> Code Editing -> Third-party Code -> Add file mask for *.ts files`. Then restart Visual Studio.
[image]

Comment: worked for me after *suspending* then *resuming* ReSharper