# Angular 7 JSON.stringify "symbol JSON cannot be resolved"

Tags: json, angular, angular7

First things first, this is my first time using Angular 7; I started making an application using Angular 7 with a c# back end and have need for serializing an object in my `component/service` before sending it to my `controller/service`.

Something like:

```
export class jsonTest  {
    json: string;
    obj: myType = {} as myType;

    this.obj.someProperty = 1234;
    this.obj.anotherProperty = 'test';

    someMethod() {
        this.json = //convert obj to json
        anotherMethod(this.json);
    }
}
```

In my search to figure out how to accomplish this, I've come across two popular suggestions, one being `JSON.stringify()` and another being `toJson()`.

However, `JSON.stringify()` throws a compile error that `symbol JSON cannot be resolved, probably it is located in an inaccessible module.`

Trying `toJson()`, it isn't recognized as a hook of any sort.

Is there some import that I'm missing?  Looking through angular documentation doesn't shed any light on my issue.

At this point, I'm considering just serializing the JSON manually, but I'd really like to avoid doing that if I can. Any suggestions?

Comment: what is the output when you open browser debug window and type in `JSON.stringify` in the console?

Comment: Are you using resharper?

Comment: @bambam, I am as a matter of fact. I know resharper has been known to throw a fit with some code usage. Let me try and disable resharper and get back to you with what happens.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34592390/visual-studio-2015-enterprise-with-resharper-10-ultimate-cannot-be-properly-r

Comment: @ABOS from browser:

"{"someProperty":"asdf","anotherProperty":"asdf"}"

Comment: ah, it is not related to angular :)

Comment: @bambam
Resharper was the culprit! Thanks much for your help! If you want to provide an answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: @ABOS bambam was able to provide me with the much needed insight I was missing! Thank you for your help!

Comment: I just found it because of the other answer. You can just close your question as a duplicate of it, then others will get redirected too.

Comment: @bambam, ah kk. I've not had to do that yet. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score -1):

You have some errors in your typescript. Try doing this instead.

```
export class JsonTest implements OnInit {
json: string;
obj: MyType = new MyType();

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.obj.someProperty = 1234;
    this.obj.anotherProperty = 'test';
}
someMethod() {
    this.json = JSON.stringify(this.obj);
    anotherMethod(this.json);
}}
```

Comment: The issue was actually Resharper throwing errors in VS2016. That was just some psudo code anyway for examples purpose :) Thanks anyways!